# Filling in blank entries

Tags: stata, missing-data

I am working with a Stata dataset that tracks a company's contract year.

However, systematically I am missing a year:

[image]

Is there a code I could quickly run through to replace the missing year with the year from the previous observation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. For the latter please provide us with example data using Stata's command `dataex`; screenshots are not helpful.

Comment: Please do read advice given before posting. Even if you don't use Statalist, which is choice, much of the advice at https://www.statalist.org/forums/help is also relevant here.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it using the check-mark.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
clear

input var year
564 2029
597 2029
653 .
342 2041
456 2041
end

replace year = year[_n-1] if missing(year)

list

     +------------+
     | var   year |
     |------------|
  1. | 564   2029 |
  2. | 597   2029 |
  3. | 653   2029 |
  4. | 342   2041 |
  5. | 456   2041 |
     +------------+
```

Comment: This is an FAQ as at https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/ Note that there is no "blank" to replace; the value is "missing".